# Table joining issue in SQL Server with TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, timestamp

I want to take current day details from three tables in SQL server. I can't join the tables with `TIMESTAMP`, the `TIMESTAMP` is different in every table. There is no common factor for joining these tables. Is there any way to join these tables. And also I can't modify the tables, those are coming from a third party service.

Queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE CAST(TIMESTAMP AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
ORDER BY CAST(TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0))

SELECT * 
FROM table2 
WHERE CAST(TIMESTAMP AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
ORDER BY CAST(TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0))

SELECT * 
FROM table3
WHERE CAST(TIMESTAMP AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
ORDER BY CAST(TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0))

SELECT 
    CAST(one.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0)) AS DATE,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), one.value) AS v1, 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), two.VALUE) AS v2, 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), three.VALUE) AS v3 
FROM
    table1 one 
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 two ON CAST(one.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0)) = CAST(two.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0)) 
LEFT JOIN 
    table3 three ON CAST(one.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0)) = CAST(three.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0))
WHERE
    CAST(one.TIMESTAMP AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
ORDER BY
    CAST(one.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0))
```

Result:

[image]

I didn't get the 2nd table and 3rd table data. eg: `2018-12-30 00:00:15.657` this time from 3rd table first row. That is not showing in the result. I want the all data.

I hope you understand. Could you please help me to solve this.

Comment: What is the specific problem? First, it sez "can't join", and next the "JOIN" works perfectly.  Please state the expected results, and how that differs from the join.  Then, so we can reproduce this, remove the jpeg or png inputs, and replace them as copy with headers/paste,   then frame each one with braces{} to maintain spacing.

Comment: @donPablo I just edited my question.

Comment: join on row_number?

Comment: @P.Salmon which row_number? You mean ID?

Comment: I assume you wish to join the 1st entry on each table the second entry on each table etc. You cannot join on id since they are not the same but you could generate a row_number on each table based on id and join on that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 and google sqlserver row_number for more.

Comment: You could improve the chances of getting a working answer by providing sample data as text in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try with `row_number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want a `full join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(one.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0)),
                CAST(two.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0)),
                CAST(three.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0))
               ) as dt,
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), one.value) AS v1, 
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), two.VALUE) AS v2, 
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), three.VALUE) AS v3 
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM table1 one
      WHERE CAST(one.TIMESTAMP AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
     ) one FULL JOIN 
     (SELECT *
      FROM table2 two
      WHERE CAST(two.TIMESTAMP AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
     ) two
     ON CAST(two.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0)) = CAST(on.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0)) FULL JOIN
     (SELECT *
      FROM table3 three
      WHERE CAST(three.TIMESTAMP AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
     ) three
     ON CAST(three.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0)) = COALESCE(CAST(one.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0)), CAST(one.TIMESTAMP AS DATETIME2(0)))
ORDER BY dt;
```

`FULL JOIN`s are tricky with filtering, which is why this uses subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Or, just modify the WHERE

```
WHERE
    CAST(one.TIMESTAMP AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
 OR CAST(two.TIMESTAMP AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
 OR CAST(three.TIMESTAMP AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: I tried this step before, But it's not working properly.